# What does the acronym MOC stand for?

Tags: terminology, moc

This is a common acronym used in the Lego community - what does MOC mean?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

MOC stands for "My Own Creation".

> MOC
>
> My Own Creation. Any LEGO creation designed and built by a LEGO fan without instructions. Generally pronounced “mock.”*

Found at [this](http://www.brothers-brick.com/lego-glossary/) Lego glossary.

Brickipedia's version from [their own glossary](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/MOC):

> MOC - My Own Creation, a fan- made LEGO model

*A side note: There may be some LEGO fans who pronounce "MOC" the way the individual letters are pronounced - effectively saying "Em-Oh-See".

Comment: You could note the grammatical conflict--I hear "a MOC" alot, given that people pronounce it as "MOCK," but I personally say "an MOC" and pronounce it "EM-OH-SEE."

Comment: Since when did the pronunciation of an acronym result in a grammatical conflict?

Answer (score 1):

A MOC or a Lego MOC, are the initials of My Own Creation, so, if you have made a creation or a Lego model out of your mind, I mean, with no instructions, you've made a MOC.