# What does "AFOL" mean?

Tags: terminology, afol

I've seen the term *AFOL* around; for example, this site has an [afol](/questions/tagged/afol) tag. What does *AFOL* stand for?

Comment: Note: when I asked this question, the [tag:afol] tag was also on [What does the acronym MOC stand for?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/135/what-does-the-acronym-moc-stand-for).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AFOL stands for "Adult Fan Of LEGO".

From an [unofficial LEGO acronym glossary](http://www.brothers-brick.com/lego-glossary/):

> AFOL
>
> Adult Fan of LEGO. The most common term used to refer to LEGO fans who are adults. Generally pronounced to rhyme with “hay-foal”.

Or from [Brickipedia's glossary](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/MOC) (also unofficial):

> AFOL - Adult Fan Of LEGO

Comment: I saw that meaning before asking, but it didn't explain the way [tag:afol] tag is being used. Is there another meaning, or is the tag usage incorrect?

Comment: The only question using that tag at the moment isn't really about adult fans.

Comment: I'd say that it was a case of incorrect tag use - perhaps the OP considers themselves an AFOL, and tagged it as such?

Comment: Thanks, all: I was wondering what it was I was missing, and the answer was that I wasn't!