# What is the official term used for building MOC models?

Tags: building, terminology, moc

I know that MOC means "my own creation" as noted [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/135/what-does-the-acronym-moc-stand-for).  What I would like to know is do you call the actual act of creating a MOC, "MOC building", or is there another official term?  I wanted to build with my son and called it 'free building' as I did not know any official term, and only just learned the acronym MOC.  I would like to know how to properly say, "Let's go ___________" (build without a plan).

edit: I think where I was confused came from the fact that I've read here and other places that using the term LEGOs is incorrect, that you are supposed to use LEGO bricks and I found that awkward to say so I thought maybe there was also a special term for building official sets versus building a MOC.

Comment: I would tend to understand "official" as "given by LEGO itself" - which isn't even the case for "MOC".

Comment: Mocking? (Come on people, _it's right there!_)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By considering a "somehow usual amongst fans" instead of "official" position (see my comment),  I have heard some fans who simply "verbed" the acronym MOC, as in, "I MOC'ed for 3 hours straight yesterday". You could probably do the same with LEGO itself, but that would be frowned upon as LEGO is supposed to be used as an adjective and so on. (When I was a child, my father used "legoter" in French, which was quite clear as to what it meant. I guess you could be "legoing" in English as well).

I'm not saying I do think it's a very good idea, and I haven't even heard that much anyway; so I would tend to agree with Grandpappy and go for a simple "build" (maybe "build something" to imply it's not a set) or even "play" (or more precisely "play with LEGO" if your son happens to sometimes play with something else (I can't fathom why, though)).

So, in short, no real "official" saying, and not even an usual one - especially considering that fans amongst themselves always use LEGO anyway, which means "what did you build recently" is always understood.

Answer (score 5):

I just use "Build".  As in: "I'm going to go build"

I'm unaware of any official term.  Even "MOC" isn't official in any way other than just a term a lot of people use.

Comment: I agree with 'build' and 'building' has a general term.  That's what I use even when I'm building an actual Set.

Comment: So I guess if there is no official term, than whatever is the most commonly used terminology would be the answer which seems to be just 'build'.  It makes sense, but I'll let this one sit just a little in case something else comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If its a "my own creation" then if one is still building it or it is still unfinished then one simply refers to it as "work in progress" or a WIP and thats how fans post photos on fansites let others know hows its is going... although i have never seen it used with offical lego sets...there are other loose terms floating about i think they where listed on the brickset fansite quite a while ago- i think you would have to do a search for the article- but i was amazed by how many there are...again its not an offical language used by fans but its the most common form of expression.