# Can you identify this torso assembly

Tags: minifigure-identification

Can anyone identify this [torso and arms](https://www.etsy.com/listing/744720287/ygritte-minifigure-game-of-thrones?ref=sold_out-1&pro=1)?
I did a search on Bricklink for torsos with 'fur' and 'belt' but couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: Can you please insert the image instead of the link? Usually, the webpage opens with popups, cookies and other unwanted stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I found [another listing](https://www.etsy.com/listing/809323985/ygritte-custom-minifigure-game-of?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=Ygritte%20Minifigure&ref=sr_gallery-1-1&organic_search_click=1) for the same minifigure on Etsy with extended description, which doesn't mention LEGO parts have been used. Otherwise that would be a selling benefit. Also, two sentences below, extracted from description, make you assume minifigure is built from non-LEGO parts.

> This custom Minifigure works with any building block set.
>
> These figures are custom figures and are only compatible with LEGO® but are not in any was associated or endorsed by them.

Now if you are still in doubt, we could check if Bricklink has them. Torso and legs seems to be in Light Bluish Gray color. While such [legs exist](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c00#T=C) as LEGO item, checking [torsos](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=2&catXrefLevel=0&colorPart=86&catType=P&catID=150), [assembled torsos](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catID=1097&catXrefLevel=0&colorPart=86&catType=P), [body parts (arms)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catID=20&catXrefLevel=0&colorPart=86&catType=P) in this color it can be be concluded that torso and arms have non-LEGO print. These still could be made of genuine LEGO parts, but print is custom.

Hair looks to be in Dark Orange, which exist both in LEGO form as [Minifigure, Hair Female Mid-Length with Braid around Sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=59363#T=C) and a color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The seller says that it was handmade, and Lego minifigures are not made like that. And it **clearly** says this in the product description:

> Game of Thrones Ygritte custom mini figure.

This most likely means that this is a [**MOC**](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/138/15028) figure. Like I said before, Lego would not bother to buy the *Game Of Thrones* license (it is already purchased by Mega Construx anyways) and they don't even spell the word "minifigure" as "mini figure." As told in the comments, the head, hair, and grey pants are not in Bricklink's database, so I'm still sticking with the fact that it's a MOC figure. I typed "head blue eyes" "orange hair" "pants grey" but none of them appear. This therefore offers more proof to my answer.

Comment: "Custom minifigure" doesn't always mean all of its components are non-LEGO or otherwise modified LEGO parts. Minifigure could be assembled from existing LEGO elements, but assembly itself doesn't appear as such item in any of the sets.

Comment: You also don't need to have a license to build your own GoT minifigure from LEGO elements. So having an answer based on the fact that LEGO doesn't hold the license for Game of Thrones isn't really accurate

Comment: And based on the price, I suspect this was not custom printed but assembled from other lego pieces.  The custom printed ones typically sell for much more.

Comment: @user3794648 Well, the head, hair, and grey pants are not in Bricklink's database, so I'm still sticking with the fact that it's a MOC figure. I typed "head blue eyes" "orange hair" "pants grey" but none of them appear. This therefore offers more proof to my answer.

Comment: @mindstormsboi [Hair](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=59363&colorID=68&in=A), [Legs](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=970c00&colorID=86&in=A)